# How to get Response Body when Server responds with 302 in Grails?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

I want to request server side an image from a different server with a GET request. If the requesting server response with status code 200 everything works fine.
But often I get FOUND 302 redirect as status code. In this case there is no **response.body** which I need.

This is the code I use to retrieve a user image from facebook. Since facebook makes a redirect I get 302 as status code and not response.body.

```
def uri = new URI("http://graph.facebook.com/1000345345345/picture?width=200&height=200")
def requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()

def request = requestFactory.createRequest(uri, HttpMethod.GET)

try {
        def response = request.execute()
        def statusCode = response.statusCode
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.FOUND) {
            log.debug "302" 
            // how do I get the response body?
        }

        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
            return response.body.bytes
        }
        else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) {
            throw new IllegalAccessError(response.statusCode.toString())
        }
} catch(ex) {
    log.error "Exception while querying $url", ex
}
return null
```

**How do I get the correct response body in case on 302?**

Comment: A 302 does not typically contain a response body. Instead, you need to follow through on the request and go to the redirected URI.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I thought that the request on GET will be redirected automatically. Isn't that the case? How do I get the redirectURI?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know your Http Client. There might be a setting to make it follow through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. You method is:

```
def queryUrl(url, ...) {}
```

You can use:

```
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.FOUND) {
            def newUrl = response.connection.responses.getHeaders().Location[0]
            log.debug "302 redirect to ${newUrl}"
            return queryUrl(newUrl, "")
        }
```

This will request the redirected url.